# Windows 8 .net focus issue form.activate has different behaviour when running with debugger

Tags: vb.net, debugging, windows-8, focus, microsoft-metro

I have written a WinForms driver safety application for a windows tablet device that will blank the screen (display a full screen blank topmost window) when it detects that the car is moving at say more that 15km/h (using the tablets GPS).

The software has worked fine under Windows 7 but I'm struggling a bit to get it working under Windows 8. My first challenge is to display the blank screen when the Metro start menu is currently displayed. So if the user has the Metro start menu displayed and the car starts moving > 15 km/h my blank screen should display... I need to steal the focus from the metro interface and display my blank window on the desktop.

To test this I wrote a simple vb.net app in 2010. It had a form with a timer firing every 3 seconds. In the Tick event I had the code:

```
    Beep()
    Me.Activate()
```

When I ran this with the debugger and pressed the windows key to show the Metro Start Menu, it worked... The focus switched back to the desktop (and my window). However, when I ran this without the debugger and did the same thing I could hear the beeps but the focus never switched back to the desktop.

Any ideas why the behaviour would be different? Any ideas on how I replicate the same behaviour I get when the debugger is attached?

I have tried a few things like AppActivate, setting the form TopMost, BringToFront but unfortunately this hasn't worked.

The only half solution I have come up with is to send a windows button keystroke but this has other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Windows specifically tries to prevent applications from stealing the foreground from other apps. See the [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation for commentary on this and the factors that can let an application come to the foreground (all of the methods you are trying essentially come down to a SetForegroundWindow call).

Note that one of the explicit blocking circumstances is "The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start Screen."

This works for you when debugging because "The process is being debugged" is one of the cases which explicitly allows foreground privileges.

Because this is a generally user-unfriendly thing to do there isn't a good general purpose way to bypass this behaviour and steal the foreground.

Likewise, normal apps cannot run on top of Modern applications or the start screen.

You may be better off locking the system by calling the [LockWorkStation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your explanation. I don't suppose there is any way to trick Windows into thinking a debugger is attached?